# What are the advantages and disadvantages of these methods of creating tables with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I found two ways to create a table in JS:

1. Using `insertRow` and `insertCell`:

   ```
   var table = document.getElementById ("table");
   var row = table.insertRow (1);
   var cell = row.insertCell (0);
   cell.innerHTML = "New row";
   ```
2. Using plain DOM operations:

   ```
   var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
   var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

   // creating all cells
   for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
     // creates a table row
     var row = document.createElement("tr");

     for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
       // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
       // the end of the table row
       var cell = document.createElement("td");
       var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell is row "+j+", column "+i);
       cell.appendChild(cellText);
       row.appendChild(cell);
     }

     // add the row to the end of the table body
     tblBody.appendChild(row);
   }
   ```

The first as I see is specially created for the table, but the second is mentioned on MDN, so I'm a bit confused what methods to use. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? When is one used over another?

Comment: I'd say use the second one. Don't forget to `tbl.appendChild(tblBody)` though!

Comment: There is 3rd method: Directly write table's codes to HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can avoid using the elements, and just put a string into an `innerHTML` you'll get the best performance.  Here are some different ways to create a table.

### Functional Code [*demo*](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/gCmGi)

We can create some functions to generate our HTML.  This code will be very fast (but could be faster).  We'll assume this data for all of these examples.

```
var heading = ['Name', 'Points'];

var data = [
  ["Joe", 50],
  ["Jack", 80],
  ["Doug <b>'the hammer'</b> Jones", 76]
];
```

We can then generate our table like so,

```
document.body.innerHTML = table(heading, data);
```

```
function wrapTag(tag, html) {
  return "<" + tag + ">" + html + "</" + tag + ">";
}


function table(head, body) {
    return wrapTag("table", thead(head)
    + tbody(body));
}

function thead(head) {
  var _th = head.map(wrapTag.bind(null, "th"));
  var _tr = wrapTag("tr", _th.join("\n"));
  return wrapTag("thead", _tr);
}

function tbody(body) {
  return body.map(tr).join("\n");
}

function tr(row) {
  var _td = row.map(wrapTag.bind(null, "td"));
  return wrapTag("tr", _td.join("\n"));
}
```

---

### KnockoutJS [*demo*](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/tDsHC)

In Knockout we can give it an object, and have it map directly to our HTML.  With the `heading` and `data` variables defined above, we map this like so.

```
ko.applyBindings({heading: heading, data: data});
```

Our HTML makes use of the `foreach` binding, which iterates over an array.  `$data` refers to the current array item.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: heading">
      <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
      <td data-bind="html: $data"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### AngularJS [*demo*](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/LDtiz)

Using the same data from above, we can create an AngularJS controller.

```
function MyTableCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.heading = heading;
  $scope.data = data;
}
```

Our HTML is similar to KnockoutJS.  One difference is the looping syntax, which lets us name our elements, e.g., `row in data`, instead of referring to elements as `$data`.

```
  <table ng-controller="MyTableCtrl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="head in heading">{{head}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-repeat="content in row" ng-bind-html-unsafe="content"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

### documentFragment [*demo*](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/AIkaK)

<sup>credit to **@Ian**</sup>

This is faster than regular DOM manipulation, and provides a nicer syntax than combining strings.

```
newTable = createTable(heading, data);
document.body.appendChild(newTable);
```

```
function createTable(h, c) {
    var frag, table, head, body;

    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    table = document.createElement("table");
    head = createHeader(h);
    body = createContent(c);

    table.appendChild(head);
    table.appendChild(body);

    frag.appendChild(table);

    return frag.cloneNode(true);
}

function createHeader(data) {
    var thead, rowEl, col, colEl, text, i, j;

    thead = document.createElement("thead")
    rowEl = document.createElement("tr");

    for (i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
        col = data[i];
        colEl = document.createElement("td");
        text = document.createTextNode(col);
        colEl.appendChild(text);
        rowEl.appendChild(colEl);
    }

    thead.appendChild(rowEl);

    return thead;
}

function createContent(data) {
    var content, row, rowEl, col, colEl, text, i, j, k, l;

    content = document.createElement("tbody");

    for (i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
        row = data[i];
        rowEl = document.createElement("tr");
        for (k = 0, l = row.length; k < l; k++) {
            col = row[k];
            colEl = document.createElement("td");
            text = document.createTextNode(col);
            colEl.appendChild(text);
            rowEl.appendChild(colEl);
        }
        content.appendChild(rowEl);
    }

    return content;
}
```

Comment: @vol7ron, nice catch, it's fixed.  I also made the tables less ugly in the demos (yay bootstrap!)

Comment: If you have actual proof for `just put a string into an innerHTML you'll get the best performance.`, I'd love to see it. Any jsPerf (which I understand doesn't always *best* exemplify the situation) I've seen in the past begs to differ (with some inconsistencies across browsers). Technically, using a `documentFragment` is most likely fastest, with the use of `document.createElement` and `.appendChild()` not far behind, but the gap between these methods is closing anyways. And I don't see how the use of slower methods like `map` is going to make it "fast"

Comment: @Ian, quirksmode did a very [extensive benchmark](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) of DOM vs innerHTML.  The gap has been closing in recent years, but it's still not quite there.  I wrote my example to be simple, but of course, functions add overhead.  DOM manipulation is functions plus additional DOM overhead.  The ideal situation for performance is to precompile a JavaScript template for each element you'd like to render.

Comment: You're joking, right? You're actually referencing that link? That uses IE 5-8 and FF 2-3? That's hardly something to reference. Like I said, jsPerfs tend to show a good consensus, which is that `innerHTML` is slowest. There's a reason why jQuery uses `documentFragment`s

Comment: I would love if you would add a documentFragment example to this answer, or create one of your own.

Comment: Hmm it wouldn't be much different from the OP's `appendChild` example, except it would be appended to the fragment instead of the document. I'll see what I can come up with and let you do what you want with it :)

Comment: Here's more or less an example: http://jsfiddle.net/EsRXf/ . Obviously it would have to be changed to use `.innerHTML` to set the `<td>`'s contents if HTML is expected, but I assumed text

Answer (score 1):

taken from this post: [insertRow vs. appendChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879563/insertrow-vs-appendchild)

insertRow would be the much better. It is supported by grade A browsers and it's less verbose and a cleaner API.

insertRow might be argued as more reliable since it's DOM[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879563/insertrow-vs-appendchild).

The appendChild method is consistently faster (albeit marginally) across all tested browsers (IE6/7, FF3, Chrome2, Opera9) when operating outside of the DOM, but when trying to modify tables within the document (a more common endeavour) it's significantly slower.

In other words: definitely use insertRow.

My personal opinion is: 1 method more clear and uses native methods

Answer (score 0):

I actually use [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) in day-to-day development, so you can do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/E996J/1/):

Bare HTML table:

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Then you can store a template in a non-JS `<script>` tag. You can assign an id or whatever to retrieve the element.

```
<script type="text/template" id="rowTemplate">
  {{#rows}}
  <tr>
    {{#items}}
    <td>
      {{.}}
    </td>
    {{/items}}
  </tr>
  {{/items}}
</script>
```

Retrieving the template is something like:

```
var template = document.getElementById('rowTemplate').innerHTML;
```

Then you need a data source. Mustache needs an object to do this:

```
var data = {
  rows : [
    {
      items : ['hello1','world1']
    },{
      items : ['hello2','world2']
    }
  ]
}
```

Rendering:

```
var usableHTML = Mustache.render(template,data);
```

You can then append `usableHTML` to your table

```
document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = usableHTML;
```